# Connect to samba share from windows 10

Tags: 16.04, samba, windows-10

I am having difficulties to connect to a samba share from Windows10. The samba-share is located on a Ubuntu server 16.04.
I did some reading on the internet and did configure the share but can't connect from windows10.

Hopefully someone can help me I'm a bit desperate right now...

Accessing the server from windows file explorer gives the following feedback:

[cannot access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehq2p.jpg)

[diagnostics misspelled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mCqx.jpg)

[diagnostics server exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI6Y2.jpg)

On forehand I did the following within the Ubuntu server:

Configuring /etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
#
# Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
#
#
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which
# are not shown in this example
#
# Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
# commented-out examples in this file.
#  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
#    differs from the default Samba behaviour
#  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
#    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
#    enough to be mentioned here
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
# "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic
# errors.

#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
   workgroup = RVNET

# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

# Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
# WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable its WINS Server
#   wins support = no

# WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
# Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
;   wins server = w.x.y.z

# This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.
   dns proxy = no

#### Networking ####
#
# Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
#
#
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which
# are not shown in this example
#
# Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
# commented-out examples in this file.
#  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
#    differs from the default Samba behaviour
#  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
#    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
#    enough to be mentioned here
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
# "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic
# errors.

#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
   workgroup = RVNET

# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

# Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
# WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable its WINS Server
#   wins support = no

# WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
# Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
;   wins server = w.x.y.z
# This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.
   dns proxy = no

#### Networking ####

# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
# 'interfaces' option above to use this.
# It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
# not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
# option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
;   bind interfaces only = yes



#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
   max log size = 1000

# If you want Samba to only log through syslog then set the following
# parameter to 'yes'.
#   syslog only = no

# We want Samba to log a minimum amount of information to syslog. Everything
# should go to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd} instead. If you want to log
# through syslog you should set the following parameter to something higher.
   syslog = 0

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


####### Authentication #######
security = user

# Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
# values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
# domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
# This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.
   dns proxy = no

#### Networking ####

# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
# 'interfaces' option above to use this.
# It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
# not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
# option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
;   bind interfaces only = yes



#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
   max log size = 1000

# If you want Samba to only log through syslog then set the following
  dns proxy = no

#### Networking ####

# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
# 'interfaces' option above to use this.
# It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
# not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
# option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
;   bind interfaces only = yes



#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
   max log size = 1000

# If you want Samba to only log through syslog then set the following
# parameter to 'yes'.
#   syslog only = no

# We want Samba to log a minimum amount of information to syslog. Everything
# should go to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd} instead. If you want to log
# through syslog you should set the following parameter to something higher.
   syslog = 0

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


####### Authentication #######
security = user

# Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
# values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
# domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
# directory domain controller".
#
# Most people will want "standalone sever" or "member server".
# Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
# running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
# new domain.
   server role = standalone server

# If you are using encrypted passwords, Samba will need to know what
# password database type you are using.
   passdb backend = tdbsam

# We want Samba to log a minimum amount of information to syslog. Everything
# should go to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd} instead. If you want to log
# through syslog you should set the following parameter to something higher.
   syslog = 0

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


####### Authentication #######
security = user

# Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
# values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
# domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
# directory domain controller".
#
# Most people will want "standalone sever" or "member server".
# Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
# running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
# new domain.
   server role = standalone server

# If you are using encrypted passwords, Samba will need to know what
# password database type you are using.
   passdb backend = tdbsam

   obey pam restrictions = yes

# This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
# password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
# passdb is changed.
   unix password sync = yes

# For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
# parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
# sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

# This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
# when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
# 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
   pam password change = yes

# This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
# to anonymous connections
   map to guest = bad user

########## Domains ###########

#
# The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = primary
# classic domain controller', 'server role = backup domain controller'
# or 'domain logons' is set
#

# It specifies the location of the user's
# profile directory from the client point of view) The following
# required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
# below)
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
# Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
# (this is Samba's default)
#   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
# point of view)
;   logon drive = H:
#   logon home = \\%N\%U

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
# in the [netlogon] share
# NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
;   logon script = logon.cmd

# This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
# password; please adapt to your needs
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

# This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the
# SAMR RPC pipe.
# The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
 add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

# This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

############ Misc ############

# Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
# on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
# of the machine that is connecting
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

# Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
# for something else.)
;   idmap uid = 10000-20000
;   idmap gid = 10000-20000
;   template shell = /bin/bash

# Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
# with the net usershare command.

# Maximum number of usershare. 0 (default) means that usershare is disabled.
;   usershare max shares = 100

# Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
# public shares, not just authenticated ones
   usershare allow guests = yes
#======================= Share Definitions =======================

# Un-comment the following (and tweak the other settings below to suit)
# to enable the default home directory shares. This will share each
# user's home directory as \\server\username
;[homes]
;   comment = Home Directories
;   browseable = no

# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
# next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
;   read only = yes

# File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   create mask = 0700

# Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
;   directory mask = 0700

# By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
# with access to the samba server.
# Un-comment the following parameter to make sure that only "username"
# can connect to \\server\username
# This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
;   valid users = %S

# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes

# Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
# users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
# The path below should be writable by all users so that their
# profile directory may be created the first time they log on
;[profiles]
   comment = Users profiles
   path = /mnt/raid5/data16
;   guest ok = no
   browseable = yes
   valid users = rick
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700
   available = yes
   public = yes
   read only = no
   writable = yes

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = yes
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
# Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
# You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
# admin users are members of.
# Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
# to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
;   write list = root, @lpadmin
```

I did use the following commands to add a group on the data16 directory.
User rick has access to the directory and I checked he can access that directory from within the Ubuntu server. I created some test-directories there.
I used the following commandline commands:

```
rick@RVSERVER16:/mnt/raid5$ sudo groupadd data16
rick@RVSERVER16:/mnt/raid5$ sudo usermod -a -G data16 rick
rick@RVSERVER16:/mnt/raid5$ sudo mkdir data16
rick@RVSERVER16:/mnt/raid5$ sudo chgrp -R data16 /mnt/raid5/data16
rick@RVSERVER16:/mnt/raid5$ sudo chmod -R 777 /mnt/raid5/data16
rick@RVSERVER16:/mnt/raid5$ sudo chmod g+s /mnt/raid5/data16
rick@RVSERVER16:/mnt/raid5$ sudo smbpasswd -a rick
Added user rick.
rick@RVSERVER16:/mnt/raid5$ sudo restart smbd
rick@RVSERVER16:/mnt/raid5$ sudo restart nmdb
rick@RVSERVER16:/mnt/raid5$ sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart
```

Finally a view on the directory info:

```
rick@RVSERVER16:/mnt/raid5$ ls -all
total 60
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root   4096 Jan 18 20:24 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Jan 18 19:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Apr 12  2016 backups
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root   4096 Jan  7 15:55 cache
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root   4096 Jan  7 15:56 crash
drwxrwsrwx  5 root data16 4096 Jan 28 14:07 data16
drwxr-xr-x 48 root root   4096 Jan  7 16:00 lib
drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff  4096 Apr 12  2016 local
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      9 Jan  7 15:50 lock -> /run/lock
drwxrwxr-x 11 root syslog 4096 Jan  7 16:01 log
drwxrwsr-x  2 root mail   4096 Aug  1 13:16 mail
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Aug  1 13:16 opt
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      4 Jan  7 15:50 run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Apr 29  2017 snap
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root   4096 Jan  7 15:55 spool
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root   4096 Jan  7 16:00 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Jan  7 15:55 www
```

Information asked by N0rbert:
rick@RVSERVER16:/mnt/raid5/data16$ smbclient -L localhost
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter rick's password:
Domain=[RVNET] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu]

```
    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    profiles        Disk      Users profiles
    print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (RVSERVER16 server (Samba, Ubuntu))
```

Domain=[RVNET] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu]

```
    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------
    RVSERVER16           RVSERVER16 server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    RVZOLDER             RV_ZOLDER

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
    RVNET                RVSERVER16
```

Comment: Does it work if connect using IP address (something like `\\192.168.11.22\\share`)? What is the output of `smbclient -L localhost` on Ubuntu (add output to your question)?

Comment: You share definition is broken. You have commented out `;[profiles]` which should serve the `/mnt/raid5/data16` path. So remove the comment `;` and try to connect via `\\rvserver16\profiles`.

Comment: I did remove the " ;"  and restarted the samba service.
Then I tried \\RVSERVER\mnt\raid5\data16 again. I got a login window but I was rejected with the smb password. Then I saw you said try to connect via \\rvserver16\profiles. And then, voila, I was connected and saw the test-directories. I am very happy.
But why do I have to put "profiles"  in the path? How does this actually work and what if there are multiple profiles. I guess a lesson in unix, I like to learn :)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Thomas the problem is solved, thanks man:
You share definition is broken. You have commented out ;[profiles] which should serve the /mnt/raid5/data16 path. So remove the comment ; and try to connect via \rvserver16\profiles. – Thomas 1 hour ago

I did remove the " ;" and restarted the samba service. Then I tried \RVSERVER\mnt\raid5\data16 again. I got a login window but I was rejected with the smb password. Then I saw you said try to connect via \rvserver16\profiles. And then, voila, I was connected and saw the test-directories. I am very happy.