# Samba share on Ubuntu server suddenly stopped showing content/files on Windows

Tags: networking, server, samba, windows-10

I have 20 computers in my office network and all the computers run Windows 10 except one which is running Ubuntu. I have setup a samba share on that machine so that others can access the share drive which I have mapped as a network drive. This worked fine for months and today for some reason the drive shows the capacity on Windows "This PC" , but when opened it says, It is empty. I tried booting one of those PCs with a Linux USB and it successfully shows the contents and no errors. Also I can access the network drive on android file manager.

I can confirm now that the samba share cannot be accessed on Windows, which worked fine earlier.
I have read some [questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000672/connect-to-samba-share-from-windows-10) here, but I can connect but content does not show.

How can I fix this issue and show the samba content on Windows 10?

Comment: You've provided no details on your Ubuntu machine; it is Ubuntu Server? a Ubuntu Core Server? or something else, and what release of that *unstated* Ubuntu product. How often do you upgrade packages?  Daily? Multiple-times daily? or less often?  These specific details (*when product & release is known*) can let us look for possible causes; otherwise you're best exploring the upgraded packages yourself having access to the machine (*we're limited to what you tell us*).

Comment: @guiverc thank you for the comment. Sorry for not providing information. It is Ubuntu server 22.04.2 LTS , I actually did not update packages because I have to go through a captive portal to connect to the internet through office network. but after the problem occurred I updated everything. But no change. I can mount the drive on windows 10 and it even shows the remaining and total storage, but when I open it it is empty. When booted to Linux live there is no problem and shows the files.

Comment: This is a Q&A site & not a forum, when you provide additional details please add them to your question (*once a comment is addressed it'll get removed*).  Also be precise; by *Linux live* do you mean its another GNU/Linux given you've not said Ubuntu, why not just be specific .. esp. given *live* systems could be *dailies* or a *released* product which will have differences with regard timing even if the same product & release.